# substitute variables in query string

Tags: aws-cloudformation

This template is working as expected. But when I change it to function Substitution, it throws an error.

Working template:

```
Parameters:
  MyS3Bucket:
    Type: String
Resources:
  createTableOriginalCsv:
    Type: 'AWS::Athena::NamedQuery'
    Properties:
      Database: default
      Description: First query to create table based on AWS bucket data
      Name: Blog1CreateTableOriginalCsv
      QueryString: >-
        CREATE table new_parquet11 WITH (format='PARQUET',
        parquet_compression='SNAPPY',  partitioned_by=array['year'],
        external_location = 's3://MyS3Bucket/optimized-data11/') AS SELECT
        id, date, element, datavalue, mflag, qflag, sflag, obstime,
        substr("date",1,4) AS year FROM original_csv WHERE
        cast(substr("date",1,4) AS bigint) >= 2015 AND cast(substr("date",1,4)
        AS bigint) <= 2019
```

Chagne the Query string above to this and it will not work:

> ```
>   QueryString: !Sub
>     - |-
>       CREATE table new_parquet11 WITH (format='PARQUET',
>       parquet_compression='SNAPPY',  partitioned_by=array['year'],
>       external_location = 's3://${MyS3Bucket}/optimized-data11/') AS SELECT
>       id, date, element, datavalue, mflag, qflag, sflag, obstime,
>       substr("date",1,4) AS year FROM original_csv WHERE
>       cast(substr("date",1,4) AS bigint) >= 2015 AND cast(substr("date",1,4)
>       AS bigint) <= 2019
> ```

How do I substitute variables in query string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CloudFormation Linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/) warns:

`E1019 Sub should be an array of 2 for Resources/createTableOriginalCsv/Properties/QueryString/Fn::Sub`

because [`Fn::Sub`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) either needs a list of two elements (a string and a variable map) or just a string. You can make it a string by removing the first `-` so that it is no longer a list containing one string:

```
  QueryString: !Sub
    |-
      CREATE table new_parquet11 WITH (format='PARQUET',
      parquet_compression='SNAPPY',  partitioned_by=array['year'],
      external_location = 's3://${MyS3Bucket}/optimized-data11/') AS SELECT
      id, date, element, datavalue, mflag, qflag, sflag, obstime,
      substr("date",1,4) AS year FROM original_csv WHERE
      cast(substr("date",1,4) AS bigint) >= 2015 AND cast(substr("date",1,4)
      AS bigint) <= 2019
```

Everything after the first `-` on that line is part of YAML's multiline syntax explained here:

https://yaml-multiline.info/